# How should I merge these two methods?

Tags: c#, oop

hello, guys!

i asked familiar question once and now i'm stuck again

what is a better way to refactor this?

ps. do not want to pass query as a parameter, searching for the most elegant solution

method1

```
public static List<string> GetWinners(Prize prize)
    {
        List<string> winners = new List<string>();

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ForteLotteryDataConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            var query = string.Concat(
                @"
                    SELECT Member.IBAN ",
                    "FROM Member, Summary ",
                    "WHERE Member.ID = Summary.WinnerID ",
                    "AND PrizeID = " + prize.ID
            );

            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            ...

            connection.Close();
        }

        return winners;
    }
```

method2

```
    public static List<string> GetDoubles(Prize prize)
    {
        List<string> doubles = new List<string>();

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ForteLotteryDataConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            var query = string.Concat(
                @"
                    SELECT Member.IBAN ",
                    "FROM Member, Summary ",
                    "WHERE Member.ID = Summary.DoubleID ",
                    "AND PrizeID = " + prize.ID
            );

            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            ...

            connection.Close();
        }

        return doubles;
    }
```

Comment: Please tag the language: looks like Java but could be one of its variants.

Comment: @Bathsheba That's C#.

Comment: @Bathsheba sorry, done

Comment: Really, I think the most appropriate thing you could do is have a method which executes a query, and have these two methods simply construct the query and return the result. Also, *use parameters* for SQL, don't build them like this.

Comment: IMO, if you want to make something maintainable, don't code query-building manually like this. Pick up a strongly typed framework and work with it, or build your own abstraction of query building. Otherwise, it's better to keep the code as you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Format` and pass the propname as a param:

```
    public static List<string> GetSomething(string propName, Prize prize)
    {
        List<string> doubles = new List<string>();

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ForteLotteryDataConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            var query = string.Format(
                @"SELECT Member.IBAN,
                    FROM Member, Summary,
                    WHERE Member.ID = Summary.{0},
                    AND PrizeID = {1}", propName, prize.ID
            );

            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            ...

            connection.Close();
        }

        return doubles;
    }
```

BTW - be carefull from SQLI's - Read about `parameterized queries`.

Comment: @A.Abramov - A string is no more than a pointer and a few bytes in the heap. Whats so big about it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could pass the type that you want as an enum, and read it. 
It'll look like so:

```
enum Target { DOUBLES, WINNERS } // add as many as you want.

public static List<string> GetTarget(Prize prize, Target lookingFor)
{
....
// define the query
    switch(lookingFor) // take care of each case in the enum.
    {
     case Target.DOUBLES:
       query = string.Concat(
            @"
                SELECT Member.IBAN ",
                "FROM Member, Summary ",
                "WHERE Member.ID = Summary.DoubleID ",
                "AND PrizeID = " + prize.ID
        );
        break;
      case Target.WINNERS:
        query = string.Concat(
            @"
                SELECT Member.IBAN ",
                "FROM Member, Summary ",
                "WHERE Member.ID = Summary.WinnerID ",
                "AND PrizeID = " + prize.ID
        );
        break;
       default: // in case you got a bad value
           //throw an exception
        break;

    }
//Do stuff with the query.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

```
public static List<string> GetWinners(Prize prize)
{
    List<string> winners = new List<string>();

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ForteLotteryDataConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        var query = string.Concat(
            @"
                SELECT Member.IBAN ",
                "FROM Member, Summary ",
                "WHERE Member.ID = Summary.WinnerID ",
                "AND PrizeID = " + prize.ID
        );

        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        ...

        connection.Close();
    }

    return winners;
}
```

**Method2**

```
public static List<string> GetDoubles(Prize prize)
    {
        List<string> doubles = new List<string>();

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ForteLotteryDataConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            var query = string.Concat(
                @"
                    SELECT Member.IBAN ",
                    "FROM Member, Summary ",
                    "WHERE Member.ID = Summary.DoubleID ",
                    "AND PrizeID = " + prize.ID
            );

            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            ...

            connection.Close();
        }

        return doubles;
    }
```

**Joining these methods**

```
protected void JoinMethods()
        {
            List<string> j = new List<string>();
            j.AddRange(this.GetWinners("Parameters goes here"); //Method 2
            j.AddRange(this.GetDoubles("Parameters goes here"); //Method 2          
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather enumerate possible cases (`enum WinnerKind`), something like that:

```
public enum WinnerKind {
  Winner = 0,
  Double = 1
}
```

...

```
public static List<string> GetWinnersData(Prize prize, WinnerKind kind) {
  List<string> result = new List<string>();

  // You don't have to concat strings
  // it's a good practice to use parametrized queries: "PrizeID = ?" 
  String query = String.Format(
    @"SELECT Member.IBAN,
        FROM Member, 
             Summary,
       WHERE Member.ID = {0}
         AND PrizeID = ?",
    kind == WinnerKind.Winner ? "Summary.WinnerID" : "Summary.DoubleID");

  using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ForteLotteryDataConnectionString"].ConnectionString)) {
    connection.Open();

    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection)) {
      // named parameters aren't supported
      command.Parameters.Add(prize.ID);

      using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (reader.Read()) 
          result.Add(Convert.ToString(reader[0].GetValue()));
      }
    } 
  }

  return result;  
}

public static List<string> GetWinners(Prize prize) {
  return GetWinnersData(prize, WinnerKind.Winner);
}

public static List<string> GetDoubles(Prize prize) {
  return GetWinnersData(prize, WinnerKind.Double);
}
```